# Section appears out of the normal flow in html

Tags: html, css

I am stacking a series of div for the structure of my web page but the last of them  overlaps the others even if they are non floating or absolutely positioned

I tried to hide the overflow and clear:both for each section I tried to put the las div in position absolute and the previous in relative but It's a bit too tricky.

my html code

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
}

.section {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.present {
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(44, 23,
                232), rgb(89,
                218, 247));
    border-image-slice: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #97A2A8;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Gloria Desideri<h1>
            <nav>Menu</nav>

</header>
<div class=page>
    <div class='section present'>
        <h1>Hi, I'm Gloria!<h1>

                <h2>I am a <span class='animation'></span>
                    <h2>

    </div>
    <div class='section about'>
        <p>I was born on October 7 2000 in Viterbo.</p>
        <p>I live in Milan.</p>
        <p>I study Computer Science at Politecnico di Milano</p>
        <p> I attended Liceo Scientifico Spallanzani</p>
        <p> I spent my fourth year of High School in California</p>
        <p>I like reading, playing guitar and learning new things</p>

    </div>
    <div class='section soft-skills'>
        <h1> My top 5 strenghts are</h1>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>01</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Humilty</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Letting one's accomplishments speak
                    for themselves; not regarding
                    oneself as more special than one is.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-even'>02</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Curiosity</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Taking an interest in ongoing experience for its own sake;
                    finding subjects and
                    topics fascinating;
                    exploring and discovering.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>03</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Creativity</h3>
                    <p class='skill-description'>Thinking of novel and productive ways to conceptualize and do things;
                        includes artistic achievement
                        but is not limited to it.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-container">
            <span class='skill-number-even'>04</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Judgment</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Thinking things through and examining them from all sides; not jumping to conclusions;
                    being able to change one's
                    mind in light of evidence;
                    weighing all evidence fairly.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>05</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Fairness</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Treating all people the same according to notions of fairness and justice; not
                    letting feelings bias decisions
                    about others; giving everyone a fair chance.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section hard-skills'>
        <div class='hard-skills-group'>
            <h1> My hard skills are</h1>
            <div class='hard-container'>
                <h2>SQL</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>C++</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Java</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>HTML5</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>CSS3</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Bootstrap 4</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>English</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Excel</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Wordpress</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>XML</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='project-history'>
            <h1> Here are some of my past projects</h1>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>Trade Inc</h1>
                <p>Android videogame on world trading.</p>
                <p>The game worked through quizzes that kids had to compete in order to get raw materials to sell and make money</p>
            </div>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>Animas</h1>
                <p>Android app for church news</p>
                <p>The app had the calendar of the local church, dayly news, prayers and the church youtube channel feed</p>
            </div>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>IMind</h1>
                <p>Mental healt Wordpress website</p>
                <p> This website was ment both as a blog to inform the users about mental health broblems and a way to get in contact with a professional counselor</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section future'>
        <div class="goals">
            <h1>My career goals are</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

I expect the last div to appear under the project history section instead it overlaps other sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.section`s have their `height` set to 300 pixels, so that's the value used to lay out the boxes. But `.soft-skills`'s content is more than 300 pixels tall and overflows its box, overlapping with `.hard-skills`.

To keep each section at least 300 pixels tall but still allow them to stretch to fit their content, use [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) instead of `height`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
}

.section {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.present {
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(44, 23,
                232), rgb(89,
                218, 247));
    border-image-slice: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #97A2A8;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Gloria Desideri<h1>
            <nav>Menu</nav>

</header>
<div class=page>
    <div class='section present'>
        <h1>Hi, I'm Gloria!<h1>

                <h2>I am a <span class='animation'></span>
                    <h2>

    </div>
    <div class='section about'>
        <p>I was born on October 7 2000 in Viterbo.</p>
        <p>I live in Milan.</p>
        <p>I study Computer Science at Politecnico di Milano</p>
        <p> I attended Liceo Scientifico Spallanzani</p>
        <p> I spent my fourth year of High School in California</p>
        <p>I like reading, playing guitar and learning new things</p>

    </div>
    <div class='section soft-skills'>
        <h1> My top 5 strenghts are</h1>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>01</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Humilty</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Letting one's accomplishments speak
                    for themselves; not regarding
                    oneself as more special than one is.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-even'>02</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Curiosity</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Taking an interest in ongoing experience for its own sake;
                    finding subjects and
                    topics fascinating;
                    exploring and discovering.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>03</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Creativity</h3>
                    <p class='skill-description'>Thinking of novel and productive ways to conceptualize and do things;
                        includes artistic achievement
                        but is not limited to it.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-container">
            <span class='skill-number-even'>04</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Judgment</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Thinking things through and examining them from all sides; not jumping to conclusions;
                    being able to change one's
                    mind in light of evidence;
                    weighing all evidence fairly.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>05</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Fairness</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Treating all people the same according to notions of fairness and justice; not
                    letting feelings bias decisions
                    about others; giving everyone a fair chance.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section hard-skills'>
        <div class='hard-skills-group'>
            <h1> My hard skills are</h1>
            <div class='hard-container'>
                <h2>SQL</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>C++</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Java</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>HTML5</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>CSS3</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Bootstrap 4</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>English</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Excel</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Wordpress</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>XML</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='project-history'>
            <h1> Here are some of my past projects</h1>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>Trade Inc</h1>
                <p>Android videogame on world trading.</p>
                <p>The game worked through quizzes that kids had to compete in order to get raw materials to sell and make money</p>
            </div>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>Animas</h1>
                <p>Android app for church news</p>
                <p>The app had the calendar of the local church, dayly news, prayers and the church youtube channel feed</p>
            </div>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>IMind</h1>
                <p>Mental healt Wordpress website</p>
                <p> This website was ment both as a blog to inform the users about mental health broblems and a way to get in contact with a professional counselor</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section future'>
        <div class="goals">
            <h1>My career goals are</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Or to enforce the 300 pixel limit, but still allow all the text to be seen, use [`overflow: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

```css
.section {
    overflow: auto;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
}

.section {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.present {
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(44, 23,
                232), rgb(89,
                218, 247));
    border-image-slice: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #97A2A8;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Gloria Desideri<h1>
            <nav>Menu</nav>

</header>
<div class=page>
    <div class='section present'>
        <h1>Hi, I'm Gloria!<h1>

                <h2>I am a <span class='animation'></span>
                    <h2>

    </div>
    <div class='section about'>
        <p>I was born on October 7 2000 in Viterbo.</p>
        <p>I live in Milan.</p>
        <p>I study Computer Science at Politecnico di Milano</p>
        <p> I attended Liceo Scientifico Spallanzani</p>
        <p> I spent my fourth year of High School in California</p>
        <p>I like reading, playing guitar and learning new things</p>

    </div>
    <div class='section soft-skills'>
        <h1> My top 5 strenghts are</h1>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>01</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Humilty</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Letting one's accomplishments speak
                    for themselves; not regarding
                    oneself as more special than one is.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-even'>02</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Curiosity</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Taking an interest in ongoing experience for its own sake;
                    finding subjects and
                    topics fascinating;
                    exploring and discovering.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>03</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Creativity</h3>
                    <p class='skill-description'>Thinking of novel and productive ways to conceptualize and do things;
                        includes artistic achievement
                        but is not limited to it.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-container">
            <span class='skill-number-even'>04</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Judgment</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Thinking things through and examining them from all sides; not jumping to conclusions;
                    being able to change one's
                    mind in light of evidence;
                    weighing all evidence fairly.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skill-container'>
            <span class='skill-number-odd'>05</span>
            <div class='skill'>
                <h2 class='skill-title'>Fairness</h2>
                <p class='skill-description'>Treating all people the same according to notions of fairness and justice; not
                    letting feelings bias decisions
                    about others; giving everyone a fair chance.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section hard-skills'>
        <div class='hard-skills-group'>
            <h1> My hard skills are</h1>
            <div class='hard-container'>
                <h2>SQL</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>C++</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Java</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>HTML5</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>CSS3</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Bootstrap 4</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>English</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Excel</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>Wordpress</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <h2>XML</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='project-history'>
            <h1> Here are some of my past projects</h1>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>Trade Inc</h1>
                <p>Android videogame on world trading.</p>
                <p>The game worked through quizzes that kids had to compete in order to get raw materials to sell and make money</p>
            </div>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>Animas</h1>
                <p>Android app for church news</p>
                <p>The app had the calendar of the local church, dayly news, prayers and the church youtube channel feed</p>
            </div>
            <div class='prj'>
                <h1>IMind</h1>
                <p>Mental healt Wordpress website</p>
                <p> This website was ment both as a blog to inform the users about mental health broblems and a way to get in contact with a professional counselor</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section future'>
        <div class="goals">
            <h1>My career goals are</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Also, [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) is its own element. Use that instead of `<div class="section">`; it's more semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems CSS property of class *section* causing this issue.

I would recommend to Change

```
.section{
   height: 300px;
}
```

to

```
.section{
  min-height: 300px;
}
```